# implementing keras version of quantile loss for regression

Tags: keras, regression, loss-function, quantile-regression

I am trying to implement Quantile loss for a regression problem based on the formula from this [article](https://medium.com/@mlblogging.k/14-loss-functions-you-can-use-for-regression-b24db8dff987) (number 14 at the end of the article):

[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def quantile():
  percentiles = [0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99]
  gamma = 1e-2
  np.random.seed(0)
  y_true = [1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 , 1.0, -0.6, -0.9, -1.0]
  y_pred = np.random.rand(12)
  
  error = bk.abs(y_true - y_pred)
  cond  = error < gamma
  quantile_loss = bk.sum(tf.where(cond, (gamma-1) * error, gamma * error), axis=-1)

quantile()
```

I would like to check if my implementation is correct considering the condition (`y_true<y_pred`) to be applied when multiplying `gamma`. Also, if this is based on percentiles, how to apply percentiles in the loss formula?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/PinballLoss

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais: Many thanks Nicolas for the valuable link